# Update all object property of an array using vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to update a single property of an object from an array using vuex.

here is my code in store file.

```
export default{
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    customers: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_MODIFIED_STATE(state, value) {
      state.customers = [
        ...state.customers.filter(item => item.Id !== value.Id),
        value,
      ];
    },
  },
```

And below code is from my `.vue` file.

```
export default {
  computed: {
    customerArray() {
      return this.$store.state.CustomerStore.customers;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations('CustomerStore', ['UPDATE_MODIFIED_STATE']),
    updateCustomers() {
      if(someCondition) {
        this.customerArray.forEach((element) => {
            element.IsModified = true;
            this.UPDATE_MODIFIED_STATE(element);
        });
      }
      /// Some other code here
    },
  },
};
```

As you can see I want to update **IsModified** property of object.
It is working perfectly fine. it is updating the each customer object.

Just want to make sure, is it correct way to update array object or I should use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked).

If yes, I should use `Vue.set`, then How can I use it here.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not mutating your array, what you do is replacing the original array with a new array generated by the filter function and the passed value. So in your example there is no need to use `Vue.set`.

You can find more information about replacing an array in the [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array).

The caveats begin however when you directly set an item with the index or when you modify the length of the array. When doing this the data will no longer be reactive, you can read more about this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

For example, consider the following inside a mutation:

```
// If you update an array item like this it will no longer be reactive.
state.customers[0] = { Id: 0, IsModified: true }

// If you update an array item like this it will remain reactive.
Vue.set(state.customers, 0, { Id: 0, IsModified: true })
```